# How to read file in android using PhoneGap Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

How can you read a file in Android using PhoneGap and Javascript? I tried several snippets of code given at different sites but failed to do so. Actually I am a beginner and know very little about Phonegap. I also tried [FileReader](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileReader)
function but don't know where to put the file which will be readed by this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FileWriter](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileWriter) full example at http://docs.phonegap.com is designed to work with the [FileReader](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileReader) full example.  FileWriter writes readme.txt and FileReader reads it back in.

Comment: It worked for me and reads the file when I put it on the sdcard but when I put the file in "assets\www" folder then it gives error " File3 = TypeError: Result of expression 'evt.target' [undefined] is not an object".Actually I dont know how to give the path when someone puts the file in assets\www folder.So can you please tell me that

Comment: Use window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326272/access-files-from-assets-www-directory

Comment: However, I can't get window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI to work. Another option would be to incorporate the file directly into your JavaScript as a string or array assignment since you must know the data at build time to put it in the assets bundle.

Comment: It's not possible to use the File APIs on the www folder. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/Sw2wThOYm8c