# Modify app assets using Phonegap's File API

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I worked on a phonegap application using *html5* for a month. I handle offline *JSON* files using *File API*.
It seems that the *JSON* files I store are automatically saved on `/mnt/sdcard/`.

The problem is, I find myself handling 3 files for each file I want.
**1** st the file packaged with my app (js/products.js)
**2** nd the remote file that sends me updates (http://website/remote_products.js)
**3** rd the local file on sdcard I update with the remote data. (`/mnt/sdcard/updated-products.js`)

**Is it possible to - *instead of saving on the sdcard* - update my app's assets using File API ?

Or create a new file in my app assets folder ?**

(the JSON file packaged with my app. Found in `js/products.js`)

If yes, how plz ?

thx

Comment: it is not possible to modify the assets

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sadly, you cannot modify the files in `/android_assets/www` with the File API.

See this answer to a slightly different question answered by one of the PhoneGap Android devs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8966227/878602

> "You can't do what you want to do. The files in the assets directory are not technically on the file system so they are not accessible via the File API. This means calling window. resolveLocalFileSystemURI() will not return you a FileEntry."

Answer (score 0):

You might consider to utilize Mott:
https://github.com/imlucas/mott, e.g. http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/04/23/story-behind-exfm/

It seems to be able dynamically version, update and persist update of any local asset.