# How can I update assets files( js css images) in phonegap android app without update my app in play/app store

Tags: android, cordova

I am using Phonegap to develop my app, so I need to package CSS,JS,JS libs, index.html to assets/www folder, and

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",4000);
```

but is there's a way to update my CSS,JS,JS libs, index.html without updating my app(**NOT** update apk file wherever from store or our own server) --  **this is because some page I need to be interactive with native and it(CSS/JS,index.html) may need to be changed .**

Sound stupid, but is there a way to satisfy this requirement, and **how about iOS solution**?

I've read from this :  [cannot modify the files in /android_assets/www with the File API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392150/modify-app-assets-using-phonegaps-file-api) , [can't get a file object from an asset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402690/android-how-do-i-create-file-object-from-asset-file)

However , I found  [copy files in assets to sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard).

**So, can I update the assets files , in some  way  ?** or this sound stupid way（**I don't know iOS solution**）:

1 copy it to sdcard
2 update the css/js/index.html 
3 super.loadUrl("/mnt/sdcard/myapp/index.html",4000);

Is there other solutions, THX ?

Answer (score 1):

For Cordova/Phonegap it's available, a **contentsync** plugin for download remote resource and update application assets or Cordova plugins without store republishing.

Check here: [phonegap-plugin-contentsync](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-contentsync)