# Can you update a PhoneGap app from a remote server?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am considering a solution that would effectively eliminate submissions to the `AppStore` and `PlayStore`. I am seeking to update my `PhoneGap` app exclusively from my server. This is easy enough by simply saving the contents of your `www` server and then loading `index.html` from there:

```
super.loadUrl("http://myserver.com/www");
```

That works but turns my mobile app effectively into a website. Is there a solution that allows you to store assets locally but update those files when newer versions arise? I know we are not allowed access to the [assets directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9393115/2591693) but perhaps saving the resources to a different directory and loading/updating there.

I am basically thinking out loud so feel free to offer suggestions on how this can be done or how you would do things differently.

Comment: I think this question is not getting enough attention!