# Copying files from android_asset folder to SD Card

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, fileapi

So, I want to play video files that are bundled in a Cordova app. To do that, I have to move them out of the `android_asset` folder and onto the SD card. I'd like to do this in JS via the File API, if at all possible.

That being said, I seem to be unable to read from that folder with my Cordova WebView.

I've tried a few different methods, but here are the two that, based on what I've read, *should* work:

```
var url = 'file:///android_asset/www/my_video_folder';
var sourceDir = new DirectoryEntry( { fullPath: url } );
var reader = sourceDir.createReader();
reader.readEntries( success, error );
```

and

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(url, success, error);
```

In both cases, the error callback is called, with `error.code == 5` (`FileError.ENCODING_ERR`).

Is what I'm doing just *not possible*? Do I have to copy the files in the Java code?

Comment: Did you look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326272/access-files-from-assets-www-directory

Comment: I did... The highest voted answer says it's not possible, but the asker seems to have gotten it working. I guess I'm trying to get some clarity.

Comment: Well,  I read the entire topic and if Simon says "no can do", then it ain't possible. You could ask him personally if there is something changed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm inclined to agree that it's not possible, but I believe it *should* be possible, so I've created a ticket at the Cordova project: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6428. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

For any one still getting difficulties, there is a plugin which can acheive this 
https://github.com/gkcgautam/Asset2SD