# Not able to access Documents directory in iOS using Cordova API (IBM Worklight 6.2)

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am storing an image through native code in the following directory

```
"/var/mobile/Applications/74299C07-49B8-42C4-8C8B-141932C73E28/Documents/userSignature.png"
```

And then, I am loading the image to a an image view in js/html in the following manner, However it's unable to get the file.

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, TRAINING_SIGNATURE.onFileSystemSuccess, TRAINING_SIGNATURE.fail);

onFileSystemSuccess: function(fileSystem){
    var filePath = this._signatureFilePath;

    var divId = "trainingSignatureImg";
    loadImageFromFile(fileSystem,filePath, function onReceivedImageObject(result){
        document.getElementById(divId).src = result;
    });

}

function loadImageFromFile(fileSystem, filePath, onReceivedImageObject){

    fileSystem.root.getFile(filePath, {create : false}, 
        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry){
            fileEntry.file(function gotFile(file){
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                    onReceivedImageObject(evt.target.result);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        }, function fail(evt){
            alert("Failed to read file "+evt);
        });

    }, function fail(evt){
        alert("Failed to get file "+evt);
    });

}
```

Preference added in iOS config

```
"<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />"
```

Can someone point out to me what I am missing? However, it works in Android, the only difference is that I have to add File System permission in Android manifest.

```
Error: Failed to get file...
```

Comment: And the error you get is?

Comment: The error callback for fileSystem.root.getFile(..)

Comment: Can you provide a demo project to debug?

Comment: I will try to make a debug app, but I had the same issue in Android. And my workaround was to store in SD card, and the same code above worked as posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235940/not-able-to-load-image-from-android-internal-memory-using-cordova-file-system-ap

Comment: And my workaround for iOS, is to pass it as Base64 encoded image back to web view and then load the src (Only for iOS).

Comment: Have you managed to find the error Arun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the absolute path of the image instead of the relative path.