# window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI is not a function

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, file-io

I created a web application that I need to convert to a mobile application, now all I have is html5/js/css files which means I don't have any www foder no platforms folder, not a cordova project ...  I started first to build the app using cordova command lines, but I couldn't, I found many problems on that, I used then https://build.phonegap.com/ , and it works fine for me. In order to read the file, I have tried this code :

```
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///android_asset/www/data/User.xml", function () {
        alert("Success");
    }, function () {
        alert(" error ");
    });
```

but, it didn't work. I added a `try catch`, the exception was :

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI is not a function
```

Do i need to add something to my code to make it work ?

Comment: Did you try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/8326484/2091181 or the answer below that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install a plugin for this to work.

Basically, run "cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file" at your application's root directory.

For detailed instructions see here, under "Accessing the Feature":
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#LocalFileSystem

**UPDATE 2019**

The correct way to add this plugin is now with this command in your project root:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
```

This is a core cordova plugin. Documentation found [here on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file)

Comment: That seems to be outdated now. Check https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file  you need to use cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file

Comment: I re-installed the plugin and my code started working on ios.
Wasted a couple hours adding logging and all of the logging wouldn't even indicate that the plugin wasn't installed. Only that a function was undefined or whatever. Errors are vague :(